# How can I create a new raster based on cell values of an existing one using R?

Tags: r, gdal, r-raster

I have a very large raster file that includes cells which have values ranging from 1 to 25. I want to create 25 separate rasters which only include the cells from the original with the same values.

I have looked into the 'raster' package for r and thought that `RasterFromCells` might be my answer but it requires cell numbers and as my original raster has 171,681,006 cells providing cell numbers for each of the cells with each value would be extremely time consuming.

Is there a function in r that I can use to automate creating a new raster that includes all the cells with a value of 1?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems a legit `r-raster` question to me, and a more generalized answer can be provided. Edited title and voted to reopen.

Comment: It's definitely a legitimate question and it has an answer (full disclosure: from me) which has been accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a reproducible example this might not be what you want, but does this help?

```
library(raster)
logo <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
logo.1 <- (logo == 1)
plot(logo.1)
```

[image: Raster with 1 only]

Comment: Yes that is exactly it! I had previously tried values(logo) ==1 and that just returned a list, I was annoyingly close! Thanks for helping!